# I want to ask someone for a clarification of his answer on superuser

Tags: discussion

I want to ask someone for a clarification of his answer to a question of superuser.  But when I try to ask the question, it says I need a "level 50 privilege", whatever that is.  Is this a paid-subscription website?

Comment: Please take the [Tour](http://superuser.com/tour) then read [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: @Arkanon There is no FAQ for [su]. Perhaps you meant the [Help Center](http://superuser.com/help)?

Answer (score 2):

No this is not a subscription based website. You need to have a certain reputation for posting comments. This is simply to ensure the quality of the site.

As @DavidPostill suggested. Please refer to the help section:

[What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation)

[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead/214174#214174)

*Posted this as an answer in the light of making sure everyone else interested notices it.*

Comment: There is no need to answer off-topic questions. Especially by copying  my comments :/

Comment: @Dzoni - How do you figure?  Questions like this should be simply migrated, then on the correct website, answered if you so desire.

Comment: I donno. While its in the site help section clearly the OP hadn't read it, and posting an answer was the obvious thing to do. And the answer would be migrated too. The biggest concequence of posting answers to OT questions ought to be loss of rep on migration, IMO.

Comment: Perhaps see this other recent Meta post: [Was I wrong answering an off-topic question?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/10726/was-i-wrong-answering-an-off-topic-question)